# Multiple Group by argument

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table with user visits

```
id | visitorid | date      | ..
1  | 12345     | 01-01-2013
2  | 12345     | 01-01-2013
3  | 12345     | 01-01-2013
4  | 99999     | 01-01-2013
...
35 | 243246    | 01-02-2013
..
```

I want to get the unique visits of one months, so an output like this

```
 day | u_visits
 1   | 33
 2   | 42
 3   | 7
```

First I wanted to group by visitorid (on each day) and then group by the day of the month. But when I tried to group by both, the result was totally wrong:

```
SELECT day(date) AS days, COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE ... GROUP BY visitorid, days
```

Anybody have an idea what's wrong?

Comment: As a "better" / "safer"  practice, get in the habit of GROUPing each and only the columns/ aliases in the SELECT that are not aggregate functions.  In your case, don't group by visitorid unless it is a field/ alias in the SELECT clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    DAY(date) AS days, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(visitorid)) AS `Unique visits`
FROM visits
GROUP BY days
```

Here, have a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71a18/3/0).